# Intersection of a sphere and a plane projected on the plane

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to get the equation of the intersection of a sphere and a plane without the "changing basis" step?

For example, if my plane $P_1$ is $$-x -y = 0$$ I'll substitute it in my sphere (centered, radius 2 for example) equation, giving me an ellipse because we projected the circle over the plane formed by the $x$-,$y$-axes and $P_1$ isn't parallel to the $xy$ plane. But what if I want to get the actual equation in the $P_1$ plane?

Do I need to change basis? And if so how do I plot, let's say $(x + y)^2 + x^2 + y^2 = 4$ onto $P_1$ as a circle ?

Comment: The intersection of a sphere and plane is either a circle or a point (degenerate circle). How are you getting an ellipse?

Comment: The intersection is in fact a circle but I see the projection of it on a non parallel plan.  [Here is a real life example](http://www.racheldevine.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/blog-RDP_5207.jpg) with the shadow of a hula hoop on the floor.

Comment: So, do you want the equation of the projection or the circle itself? If the latter, it just confuses things a bit to bring in projections of this circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why avoid the change in basis? I think that's a bad plan.

Sure, you can define a plane as points $\vec{p}$ that fulfill $\vec{p} \cdot \vec{n} = d$, but that definition does not fix any coordinate system on the plane. To do that, you need a point on the plane to use as the origin for the coordinate system, and one unit vector to define the direction of one of the axes. (The other unit vector is perpendicular to both that one, and the plane normal $\vec{n}$, so it can be determined using a vector cross product.)

Let's say you define your plane and a coordinate system on it using three vectors. $\vec{c} = (x_c , y_c , z_c)$ is the origin on that coordinate system, $\vec{u} = ( x_u , y_u , z_u )$ defines the direction and scale of the $u$ axis on the plane ($\vec{u}$ being one $u$ unit long), and $\vec{v} = ( x_v , y_v , z_v )$ defines the direction and scale of the $v$ axis on the plane. Let's assume the $u$ and $v$ axes are perpendicular, so $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} = 0$.

The unit normal vector of the plane is $\hat{n} = ( x_n , y_n , z_n)$,
$$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{u} \times \vec{v}}{\left\lVert\vec{u}\right\rVert \, \left\lVert\vec{v}\right\rVert} = \frac{\vec{u} \times \vec{v}}{\sqrt{ \left( \vec{u} \cdot \vec{u} \right) \left( \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} \right) }} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
and if
$$d_n = \hat{n} \cdot \vec{c} = x_n x_c + y_n y_c + z_n z_c \tag{2}\label{2}$$
then the equation for the plane is
$$\hat{n} \cdot \vec{p} - d_n = 0 \qquad \iff \qquad x_n x + y_n y + z_n z - d_n = 0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$

Point $(u, v)$ on the plane coordinate system is at
$$\begin{cases}
x = x_c + u x_u + v x_v \\
y = y_c + u y_u + v y_v \\
z = z_c + u z_u + v z_v \end{cases}\tag{4}\label{4}$$

Correspondingly, if point $(x, y, z)$ is on the plane, i.e.
$$x_n x + y_n y + z_n z - d_n = 0$$
and $u$ and $v$ axes are perpendicular, $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}$, then the point corresponds to plane coordinates $(u, v)$,
$$\begin{cases}
u = \frac{(x - x_c) x_u + (y - y_c) y_u + (z - z_c) z_u}{x_u^2 + y_u^2 + z_u^2} \\
v = \frac{(x - x_c) x_v + (y - y_c) y_v + (z - z_c) z_v}{x_v^2 + y_v^2 + z_v^2} \end{cases} \tag{5}\label{5}$$

If, for some reason, $u$ and $v$ axes are not perpendicular, you can use
$$u = \frac{x_v y_c - y_v x_c + x y_v - y x_v}{x_u y_v - y_u x_v}, \qquad
v = \frac{x_c y_u - y_c x_u + y x_u - x x_u}{x_u y_v - y_u x_v}$$
if $\lvert x_u y_v - y_u x_v \rvert \ge \lvert x_u z_v - z_u x_v \rvert$ and $\lvert x_u y_v - y_u x_v \rvert \ge \lvert y_u z_v - z_u y_v \rvert$; or
$$u = \frac{x_v z_c - z_v x_c + x z_v - z x_v}{x_u z_v - z_u x_v}, \qquad
v = \frac{x_c z_u - z_c x_u + z x_u - x z_u}{x_u z_v - z_u x_v}$$
if $\lvert x_u z_v - z_u x_v \rvert \ge \lvert x_u y_v - y_u x_v \rvert$ and $\lvert x_u z_v - z_u x_v \rvert \ge \lvert y_u z_v - z_u y_v \rvert$; or
$$u = \frac{y_v z_c - z_v y_c + y z_v - z y_v}{y_u z_v - z_u y_v}, \qquad
v = \frac{y_c z_u - z_c y_u + z y_u - y z_u}{y_u z_v - z_u y_v}$$otherwise.

---

Let's work out OP's example case.

The plane coordinate system origin is at the 3D origin, so $\vec{c} = ( 0, 0, 0 )$.

If we use $\vec{u} = ( 1, -1, 0 )$ and $\vec{v} = ( 0, 0, 1 )$, their cross product is $\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = ( -1, -1, 0 )$ which matches OP's plane normal; but, because $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert = \sqrt{2} \ne \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = 1$, the plane coordinate system would be squished. Let's choose $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert = 1$, but in the direction of $( 1 , -1 , 0)$; we have
$$\begin{array}{l}
\vec{u} = ( \sqrt{1/2} ,\, -\sqrt{1/2} ,\, 0 ) \\
\vec{v} = ( 0 ,\, 0 ,\, 1 ) \\
\hat{n} = ( -\sqrt{1/2} ,\, -\sqrt{1/2} ,\, 0 ) \end{array}$$
where $\hat{n}$ is calculated using $\eqref{1}$. The equation of the plane is
$$-\sqrt{1/2} x - \sqrt{1/2} y = 0 \qquad \iff \qquad y = -x$$

We can now use $\eqref{5}$ to find the $(u, v)$ coordinates for any point $(x, y, z) = (x, -x, z)$ on the plane:
$$\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{1/2} x + \sqrt{1/2} x = \sqrt{2} x \\
v = z \end{cases}$$
Note that $u = \sqrt{2} x$ also means $x = \sqrt{1/2} u$.

A sphere of radius 2 centered at origin fulfills
$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2^2$$
i.e.
$$z = \pm \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$$
Substituting $y = -x$ to pick only the points on the plane we have
$$z = \pm \sqrt{4 - 2 x^2}$$
Calculating the $(u, v)$ coordinates for points $z = \pm \sqrt{4 - 2 x^2}$ we get
$$\begin{cases}
u = \sqrt{2} x \\
v = \pm \sqrt{4 - 2 x^2} \end{cases}$$
Substituting $x = \sqrt{1/2} u$ to $v$, and noting that $2 (\sqrt{1/2} u)^2 = u^2$, we get
$$v = \pm \sqrt{4 - u^2} = \pm 2 \sqrt{1 - u^2}$$
which describes a circle of radius 2 centered at origin in the $(u, v)$ coordinates.

---

Let's pick a harder example, but with $\vec{c}$ still at origin.

Say, $$\begin{cases}\vec{u} = ( \sqrt{2} ,\, \sqrt{2} ,\, \sqrt{2} ) \\
\vec{v} = ( \sqrt{3} ,\, -\sqrt{3} ,\, 0 ) \end{cases}$$
Here, $\lVert\vec{u}\rVert = \lVert\vec{v}\rVert = \sqrt{6} \approx 2.449$.

Using $\eqref{1}$ we find
$$\hat{n} = \left( \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} ,\, \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} ,\, -\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \right )$$
so the equation of this plane is
$$\hat{n} \cdot \vec{p} = x \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} + y \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}} - z \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} = 0$$
If we multiply both sides by $\sqrt{6}$, we get a bit nicer form:
$$x + y - 2 z = 0 \qquad \iff \qquad y = 2 z - x$$

Using $\eqref{5}$we can find the $(u, v)$ coordinates for any 3D point on the plane, $(x, y, z) = (x, 2 z - x, z)$:
$$u = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} z, \qquad v = \frac{x - z}{\sqrt{3}}$$

---

---

In a comment in October 2018, amd pointed out that we can derive the implicit equation using a matrix representation for the [quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) in [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). (We still do the coordinate system change, so we'll still need $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{c}$: the u and v axis vectors for the plane coordinate system, and the location of the origin of that coordinate system.)

Let
$$\mathbf{r} = \left [ \begin{matrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad \mathbf{Q} = \left [ \begin{matrix}
q_{xx} & q_{xy} & q_{xz} & q_x \\
q_{xy} & q_{yy} & q_{yz} & q_y \\
q_{xz} & q_{yz} & q_{zz} & q_z \\
q_x & q_y & q_z & q \end{matrix} \right ]$$
Symmetric matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ can represent any quadric (here, implicit surface in 3D using a second-degree polynomial), because
$$\mathbf{r}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{r} = 0 \quad \iff \quad
\begin{array}{lclclcl}
q_{xx} x^2 &+& q_{xy} x y &+& q_{xz} x z &+& q_{x} x & + \\
q_{xy} y x &+& q_{yy} y^2 &+& q_{yz} y z &+& q_{y} y & + \\
q_{xz} z x &+& q_{yz} z y &+& q_{zz} z^2 &+& q_{z} z & + \\
q_x x   &+& q_y y   &+& q_z z   &+& q   & = 0 \end{array}$$
ie.
$$\mathbf{r}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{r} = q_{xx} x^2 + q_{yy} y^2 + q_{zz} z^2 + 2 q_{xy} x y + 2 q_{xz} x z + 2 q_{yz} y z + 2 q_x x + 2 q_y y + 2 q_z z + q = 0 \tag{7}\label{NA7}$$
So, in 3D, symmetric matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ can describe any surface that can be described in implicit form using a second-degree polynomial in Cartesian coordinates. All you need to do to construct $\mathbf{Q}$ is know the implicit polynomial form for your quadric, then compare it to $\eqref{NA7}$ to extract the coefficients.

Now, if we define
$$\mathbf{p} = \left [ \begin{matrix} u \\ v \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad \mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \vec{u} & \vec{v} & \vec{c} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} u_x & v_x & c_x \\ u_y & v_y & c_y \\ u_z & v_z & c_z \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
we can use
$$\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{M} \mathbf{p}$$
i.e., use the matrix $\mathbf{M}$ that describes the plane, to map our 2D homogenous coordinates $\mathbf{p}$ on the plane, to the full 3D homogenous coordinates. Then, we can write $\eqref{NA7}$ as
$$\mathbf{p}^T \mathbf{M}^T \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{M} \mathbf{p} = 0 \tag{6}\label{NA6}$$
as the implicit equation of the quadric described by matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ intersecting with the plane that passes through origin, has axes $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, and plane origin at $\vec{c}$.

---

If we look at OP's example case, then
$$\vec{u} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \sqrt{1/2} \\ -\sqrt{1/2} \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{v} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\vec{c} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix} \right ], \quad
\mathbf{Q} = \left [ \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
where $\mathbf{Q}$ represents a sphere centered at origin, radius 2 (i.e., $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 4 = 0$). Then,
$$\mathbf{M} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \sqrt{1/2} & 0 & 0 \\
-\sqrt{1/2} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$$
and $\eqref{NA6}$ simplifies to
$$u^2 + v^2 - 2^2 = 0$$
as expected: a circle of radius 2 centered at origin.

---

In fact, for any quadric described by $\mathbf{Q}$ intersecting a plane described by $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{c}$, the implicit equation of the intersection (in plane coordinates $(u, v)$) is
$$C_{uu} u^2 + 2 C_{uv} u v + C_{vv} v^2 + 2 C_{u} u + 2 C_{v} v + C_{0} = 0 \tag{8}\label{NA8}$$
where $$\begin{aligned}
C_{uu} &= q_{xx} u_x^2 + q_{yy} u_y^2 + q_{zz} u_z^2 + 2 q_{xy} u_x u_y + 2 q_{xz} u_x u_z + 2 q_{yz} u_y u_z \\
C_{vv} &= q_{xx} v_x^2 + q_{yy} v_y^2 + q_{zz} v_z^2 + 2 q_{xy} v_x v_y + 2 q_{xz} v_x v_z + 2 q_{yz} v_y v_z \\
C_{uv} &= q_{xx} u_x v_x + q_{xy} u_x v_y + q_{xz} u_x v_z \\ 
\;     &+ q_{xy} u_y v_x + q_{yy} u_y v_y + q_{yz} u_y v_z \\
\;     &+ q_{xz} u_z v_x + q_{zy} u_z v_y + q_{zz} u_z v_z \\
C_{u}  &= q_{xx} u_x c_x + q_{xy} u_x c_y + q_{xz} u_x c_z + q_x u_x \\
\;     &+ q_{xy} u_y c_x + q_{yy} u_y c_y + q_{yz} u_y c_z + q_y u_y \\
\;     &+ q_{xz} u_z c_x + q_{yz} u_z c_y + q_{zz} u_z c_z + q_z u_z \\
C_{v}  &= q_{xx} v_x c_x + q_{xy} v_x c_y + q_{xz} v_x c_z + q_x v_x \\
\;     &+ q_{xy} v_y c_x + q_{yy} v_y c_y + q_{yz} v_y c_z + q_y v_y \\
\;     &+ q_{xz} v_z c_x + q_{yz} v_z c_y + q_{zz} v_z c_z + q_z v_z \\
C_{0}  &= q_{xx} c_x^2 + q_{yy} c_y^2 + q_{zz} c_z^2 + q \\
\;     &+ 2 q_{xy} c_x c_y + 2 q_{xz} c_x c_z + 2 q_{yz} c_y c_z \\
\;     &+ 2 q_x c_x + 2 q_y c_y + 2 q_z c_z \\
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thanks for this precise and clean answer @nominal-animal where there's no room for ambiguity. It was in the end effortless to find another way to turn back to changing basis.

Comment: something disturbs me at the end of your first example. Your last equation, once developed, gives us $v^2 + 4u^2 = 4$, why don't we have the equation of a sphere ?

Comment: I got it sorry for the disturbance

Comment: @Deewy: No worries!

Comment: If you are interested, I am trying to develop a generic way to achieve this result for any plans or any implicit equations. Since I struggle with Sage I posted it [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45105860/a-generic-way-to-get-the-intersection-curve-between-a-plan-and-a-volume-in-the-p).

Comment: @Deewy: (It's *plane*, not *plan*.) Just substitute the expressions of $x(u,v)$ ($x$ as a function of $u$ and $v$), $y(u,v)$, and $z(u,v)$ -- equation (4) -- into the implicit function: that gives you an implicit function in $u$ and $v$, in the plane coordinate system, that is the slice of the implicit object on that plane. (I should move to Sage, because it is open source, but having used Maple since mid-1990s, I'm finding excuses not to ...)

Comment: Let $M = \small{\begin{bmatrix}\vec u&\vec v&\vec c\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}$. If $Q$ is the homogeneous matrix of a quadric (such as the sphere in the question), then the conic that results from its intersection with the plane is $M^TQM$. This is equivalent to the substitution that you described and works for any parameterization $M$ (a.k.a. coordinate system) of the plane.

Comment: @amd: Interesting! But, I can't make that $M$ work. Should it be $M = \left [ \begin{matrix} \vec{u} & \vec{v} & \vec{n} & \vec{c} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$, i.e. a 4x4 matrix? And if so, with $p = \left [ \begin{matrix} u \\ v \\ w \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right ]$, is $\begin{cases} p^T M^T Q M p = 0 \\ w = 0 \end{cases}$ the solution OP is looking for? It seems to me that expanding that a bit (for us non-mathematicians) might provide a better answer than mine.

Comment: No. It should be a $4\times3$ matrix. It maps from a coordinate system of $P_1$ only ($\mathbb{RP}^2$) to one of the entire space ($\mathbb{RP}^3$). $M^TQM$ is a $3\times3$ symmetric matrix—a conic in $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Another way to understand $M$ is that $M(s,t,1)^T$, which is $s\vec u+t\vec v+\vec c$ after dehomogenization, is a parameterization of $P_1$.

Comment: @amd: Ah, so Q is a 4x4 matrix describing the quadric in homogenous coordinates; that's what you meant by "homogenous matrix of a quadric". In other words, $Q = \left [ \begin{matrix} a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & b \end{matrix} \right ]$ describes a sphere centered at origin with radius $\sqrt{-\frac{b}{a}}$ using $p^T Q p = 0$. Yes, this seems a better mathematical approach to me. Will you write that as an answer, or shall I try to append this to mine? OP did seem to search for something very much like that.

Comment: I don’t know about “better.” It’s a fancy way of performing the substitutions that you’ve described. I’ll see if I’ve covered this before in another answer. If not, I’ll write something up here.

Comment: @amd: I do think it is better, because it is closer to what the OP asked.  I'd be delighted if you could check the added final section in my answer above, to see if I've made any obvious mistakes or mischaracterised anything.  Do remember that as usual, I am trying to describe how to apply the math, rather than describe the math itself; I'm not that good at math proper, I just use it as a tool to solve various types of problems.

Comment: A couple of corrections, otherwise it looks good: $\mathbf Q$ should be symmetric by convention (strictly, it doesn’t have to be, but only the symmetric part contributes to the quadratic form) and after eqn (6), you’re _intersecting_ the quadric with the plane, not _projecting_ it. (There is a similar-looking expression for the outline of a quadric under central projection onto a plane, though.)

Comment: If you want to make (6) seem less like it came out of nowhere, it’s derived by setting $\mathbf r=\mathbf M\mathbf p$.

Comment: @amd: Definitely; thanks a lot! The new wording still needs a look-over, but the fact that it leads to $\eqref{NA8}$ makes it definitely better than my original answer. (I used Sagemath to calculate it symbolically, so barring typos and transcription errors, it should be correct.) If you have any further fixes or suggestions, do comment or edit; they are truly appreciated!